# Find index of an (sub)item in a 2D list with a 2D index

Tags: python, list, indexing, numbers, sublist

This isn't an easy question, kinda tricky and dunno if solvable with all the restrictive conditions.
So I have this number in my list and I need a way to retrieve its index, the problem is that my list is a 2D list so I can't really apply the `.index()` method. Otherwise I'd have to pass in one of my 1D lists that are inside of this 2D list. When what I want is actually the index of the number that is inside this 1D list.

I can't find the index of the sublist first(the 1D list) because all I have is the number I want to find the index of, I don't have the sublist.
One other major issue is the fact that this same number can be found in more than one sublist, in this case finding this number would return more than one index.

```
my2D_list =[[5, 4, 8, 3, 6], [3, 5, 0, 6, 7], [9, 8, 0, 1, 2], [9, 7, 4, 8, 4], [7, 2, 0, 5, 3]]
#I placed in this list the numbers I need to find the index of in my2D_list.
items_to_find_the_index_of= [9, 8, 8, 0, 3]
```

I would need my output to look something like:

```
9 = my2D_list[2][0] and my2Dlist[3][0]
```

And same for all the numbers in the items_to_find_the_index_of list.
I don't even know if this problem is really solvable the way I need it to but thank you for your time and efforts to helping me find a trick fix.

Rouba.

Comment: do you want to find just the first occurrence or all the occurrences?

Comment: I do need to find all the occurences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items_to_find_the_index_of = [9, 8, 8, 0, 3]
index_container = []
for item in items_to_find_the_index_of:
    indexes = []
    for index, sub_lst in enumerate(my2D_list):
        try:
            indexes.append((index, sub_lst.index(item)))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    index_container.append(indexes)

print(index_container)
```

**Output:**

```
[[(2, 0), (3, 0)], [(0, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)], [(0, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3)], [(1, 2), (2, 2), (4, 2)], [(0, 3), (1, 0), (4, 4)]]
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal but that's not really what I'm trying to do, I would need to find the index of the value 9 as a list (ex: [2][0] and [3][0]  or [2,0] and [3,0]) cz each of these indexes is the location of something in my program and that's what I need to sort, but my sorted list is the 1D list of numbers so I need to retrieve their indexes so I can sort those according to the sorted list of numbers.

Comment: I’m not sure yet Vishal, haven’t had time to work on it today yet but I will as soon as I can, it’s not really the output I needed but I will review the code as soon as I find the time to, thank you !

Comment: Hello Vishal, your function gives me the index of each number in the sublists when what I want is the index of each number in my2D_list not in its sublists.
I modified my question to make it more explicit showing how I need the output to be. I wanna be able to access the numbers of my list in my2D_list from their indexes which is not possible with the indexes your function retrieves because it only retrieves the index of the value inside the sublist not in my2D_list as a whole, which I don't need cz these indexes don't give me access to the value of my number in my2D_list.

Comment: This is the reason why I didn't accept your answer, I don't wanna put a check mark otherwise others will think the answer has been found when it hasn't yet, in this case they won't take the time to look for an answer. But I did upvote your answer as soon as I saw it cz there was some logic behind it that solves part of the problem just not fully or at least not the way I need it to be solved to be able to access the value of my numbers in the 2D_list, I named it 2D_list intentionally cz u need 2 indexes to access a value in it bcz of the sublists: my2D_list[sublist index][nb index in sublist]

Comment: Thank you Vishal but no need to keep trying, I can solve it thanks to your answers but I have other assignments I need to finish, can't stay stuck on one same problem when I have 20 others to complete for today. This function and the previous one are complementary, your first one returns the indexes of the numbers in the sublist and the second one returns the indexes of the sublists that contain the number in my2D_list. A combination of both would lead to my answer but each alone doesn't give me a way to access the position of my number in my2D_list. So thank you, it'll be fine.

Comment: Now this looks great, this is exactly what I needed, thanks ! :)

Comment: lol who cares, if someone reviews the question they will see it has been solved, there's no need for anyone to read the comments and I like keeping track of stuff so I won't delete them unless I am convinced it's necessary.